# varied input items in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a html form with html and had inputs of item, comment and visible. What i would like to do is to be able to input these variables to sql by creating a code that cycles through with these protocols:
     if all fields are blank, all are filled or only one or two are filled so it can only add said filled data to mysql table.
     Example of one of the codes i used was

```
            if($nitem != ' ' and $comment != ' ')
{$query = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET 
item = '$nitem', comment = '$comment', visible = $visible
WHERE titem.item ='$item'";
$sqlhandle = mysql_query($query, $connection);}
if (!$sqlhandle){echo 'create all failed' . mysql_error();
}else{break;}
```

I used the break but it keeps cycling through ALL the queries done and thats where i need help. As usual, i'm a total noob in this so i'd appreciate it if you have patience and understanding with me. Thank you.

UPDATE: i did an echo to generate sql and it returns a statement where all the codes wher run, i.e if only the item field had been edited with to eg: milk, it gives me item as milk, comment as blank and visible as 1 (i set default values as blank and visible as 1 if fields weren't filled with anything)

full code

```
    $item = $_POST['item'];
$nitem = $_POST['nitem'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
if(!isset($_POST['visible']))
{$visible = 1;}
else
{$visible = $_POST['visible'];}


     //for when all is true
if($nitem != ' ' and $comment != ' ')
{$query = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET 
item = '$nitem', comment = '$comment', visible = $visible
WHERE titem.item ='$item'";
$sqlhandle = mysql_query($query, $connection);}
if (!$sqlhandle){echo 'create all failed' . mysql_error();
}else{break;}



//for when all is false
if($nitem = ' ' and $comment = ' ' )
{echo 'please go back and edit a field.';
}else{break;}


//for when nitem and comment is true
if($nitem != ' ' and $comment != ' ')
{$query = "UPDATE shop.titem SET item = $nitem, comment = $comment
WHERE item = $item";
$sqlhandle = mysql_query($query, $connection);}
if (!$sqlhandle){echo 'item and comment write failed' . mysql_error();
}else{break;}


//for when nitem only is true
if($nitem !=' ' and $comment = ' ')
{$query = "UPDATE shop.titem SET item = $nitem
WHERE item = $item";
$sqlhandle = mysql_query($query, $connection);}
if (!$sqlhandle){echo 'item write failed' . mysql_error();
}else{break;}


//for where comment only is true
if($comment != ' ' and $nitem = ' ')
{$query = "UPDATE shop.titem SET 
        comment = $comment WHERE titem.item = $item";
$sqlhandle = mysql_query($query, $connection);}
if(!$sqlhandle){echo 'comment write failed' . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Is this a legacy application? Using the ancient `mysql_query` method is usually a really bad idea, it's very easy to introduce [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you forget to [properly escape user data](http://bobby-tables.com/php). It doesn't look like you're doing any escaping here which is very worrying.

Comment: Do an echo to get generated SQL and let us know what SQL is executed.

Comment: i dont know much about using mysqli at the moment so i'm just sticking to this for learning purposes. However, for some reason, replacing mysql_fetch_array with mysqli_fetch_array didn't work for me as with some other mysqli commands and i dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of your validation checks for a space and some of them assigning spaces instead of validating (you had "=" instead of "==") , I have minimised and fixed some stuff from your code you posted and came up with following,

```
    $item   = $_POST['item'];
    $nitem  = $_POST['nitem'];
    $comment= $_POST['comment'];

   if(!isset($_POST['visible'])){
        $visible = 1;
   }else{
        $visible = $_POST['visible'];
   }


     //for when all is true
   if(trim($nitem)!= '' and trim($comment) != ''){
           $query = " item = '".$nitem."', comment = '".$comment."', visible = $visible ";
   }else{
           $message = 'please go back and edit a field.';   
   }

   //for when nitem and comment is true
   if(trim($nitem)!= '' and trim($comment) != ''){
       $query = " item = '".$nitem."', comment = '".$comment."' ";
   }

   //for when nitem only is true
   if(trim($nitem) != '' and trim($comment) == ''){
       $query = " item = '".$nitem ."' ";
   }

   //for where comment only is true
   if(trim($comment) != '' and trim($nitem) == ''){
       $query = " comment ='". $comment ."' " ;
   }

    $mainquery = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET ". $query ." WHERE titem.item = '".$item."'";
    $sqlhandle = mysql_query($mainquery, $connection);

   if(!$sqlhandle){
      echo $message . mysql_error();
   }
```

If I were you, and I had this requirement I would take a different approach, but I didn't want to change your concept which will confuse you. Also I dont know whats the full requirement is.  Anyway try to adapt my code and see how it goes, I have removed all the breaks and there is only one place that sql queries get execute.

Think this will help you to fix the issue...

P.S : Always try to write readable code, it will help you in future :)

Comment: can i use an elseif instead as i have several more queries?

Comment: Yes you can use elseif, but the reason you code wont break, is because you if condition was failing

Comment: whenever i use "" it gives me an error with the returned data at $_POST['item'] or whatever it is, hence why i do ' ' or " " as they are both the same thing. I think POST actually returns a white space cuz i dont get errors when i do    if ($item = ' '){echo $item} after doing $item = $_POST['item'] else i get error "undefined variable $item"

Comment: Can you post the full code where you assign $_POST variables as well (Edit your question to add the extra code bit)

Comment: post edited to contain all the data. What do you think?

Comment: my apologies for the scattered code. If you have a better alternative for cycling through data and inputting only a select data to sql table please do let me know. This was all that came to mind

Comment: First try my code above and see that fixes your current problem and you could save data to the table. Otherwise you'll fed-up with this :) Once its all good try to optimise your code. First the MVP :). So did you tried my answer? does it work for you?

Comment: no. still does the same thing as before except it now gives me sql errors eg : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stuff for you WHERE titem.item = 'caramel'' at line 1   when i try to edit only item

Comment: Do an echo $mainquery; straight  after '$mainquery = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET ". $query ." WHERE titem.item = '$item'";' post the SQL, I'll show you where the error is.

Comment: my apologies. My internet only runs at night at the moment and  my session was terminated at that time, hence why i couldn't reply. From running the echo, I see that all is running fine except for the fact that it still cycles through all the queries.                                 UPDATE shop.titem SET comment = fun awesome WHERE titem.item = 'caramel'please go back and edit a field.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'awesome WHERE titem.item = 'caramel'' at line 1

Comment: I have change the code to correct the SQLs. SQL is failing because string concatenation issues. I suggest you to use exact code I posted. When you say its still cycle through all SQLs, did you mean all if statements are always "TRUE"?

Comment: yes....that's weird, i get "unexpected "{" in line 46" when i run the new code...that being at 'for where comment only is true'

Comment: There is a missing parentheses before the "!=", replace the line with following,
   `if(trim($comment) != '' and trim($nitem) == ''){`   . I have also changed the code above

Comment: yes, its working now. Thank you very much. If you have a suggestion on another way ot doing this i'll be happy to hear. Thanks again.

Comment: my questions now are: why is  the last code with "only comments selected" isolated for others and have its own $sqlhandle and why are there dots where the variables are written in $query?

Comment: i edited out the code with $sqlhandle under the part with "comment only" and also did if(!isset($sqlhandle)) instead of if(!$sqlhandle) because it was giving sql error when the form is left blank. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry its my bad having its own $sqlhandle at the last "if" block, It doesn't need to be there, I missed it. I changed the answer and removed it. The dots are to concat the variable strings, because you need single quotes to say these variables are string for the SQL.        This is way your code is more easy to understand and easy to find any errors.

Comment: As another better way to do this could be use an Ajax call to send the data as an JSON object from the form to the php where you do the processing, and access the object through a foreach loop, and build the UPDATE query within the loop. This would be a much cleaner way. And there are more ways to do what you are tying to do. This is just other way to do it :).

Comment: Lol. Thanks. I'm only good with Php and that's why. Thanks again though. Will try amd improve myself over time